# How to create animation of the working of a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am interested to know how to make an animation of the working of a web application similar to the link provided below:

https://about.canva.com/

The animation i am talking about is "It has everything you need for amazing design" section on the page. Animation and the icons getting highlighted in sync with animation on right side. How is it possible??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using CSS `transition` and `opacity` properties.

Change position and opacity of HTML element (e.g., `div`) using JavaScript.

There are JS libraries for animation, however, stitching it by yourself will be good practice!

For example, if I wans to toggle `div` element, I can do something like:

```
function toggle() {
    document.getElementById('div01').style.left = '100px';
    document.getElementById('div01').style.opacity = 0;
}
```

If `transition` of `div01` '0.1s,' `opacity` and `position` will be changed for 0.1s.

You can put many other elements in `div` element like your example, then hide them at one by hiding the top `div` element.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yfuLb9d0/2/.

Comment: Could you please specify the JS libraries for animation ??

Comment: @Pamela Check tutorialzine.com/2017/04/… and sitepoint.com/our-top-9-animation-libraries.